# How to reference same view model in different views

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a view model that inherits from observablecollection class of type ParentModel. That view model is bound to a button in a user control that when clicked it will add a new entry in the datagrid control in the mainwindow. That datagrid is also bound to the view model but when I am trying to add a new parent there are no new entry/rows that appear to the datagrid. My question is how do I reference the same instance of view model from the button in a user control to the datagrid control?

Here is a sample code

View Model:

```
public class ParentViewModel : ObservableCollection<ParentModel>
{

    public void AddParent(ParentModel parentModel)
    {
        Add(parentModel);
    }

}
```

Button from user control XAML:

```
<Button Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="btnAddParent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Add Parent" Width="98" Background="{x:Null}" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Command="{Binding AddParentCommand, Source={StaticResource parentViewModel}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

Datagrid from mainwindow XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgvParent" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" SelectionMode="Single" BorderThickness="2" Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue"  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource parentViewModel}}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserAddRows="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PId}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Id" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PLastName}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Last Name" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PFirstName}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="First Name" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PMiddleName}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Middle Name" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PAddress}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Address" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PContactNo}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Contact Number" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PEmail}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Email" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PCreatedOn}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Created On" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PUpdatedAt}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Updated At" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

**EDIT:**

In my mainwindow there is another view model that is bound to the grid, that view model is used to make the user control visible when clicking a button.

MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Constructors
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _showUserControlCommand = new ShowUserControlCommand(ShowUserControl, IsExecutable);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Events
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public bool IsExecutable(object context)
    {
        return true;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Commands and Properties
    private Visibility _visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    public Visibility ChangeControlVisibility
    {
        get { return _visibility; }
        set { _visibility = value; OnPropertyChanged("ChangeControlVisibility"); }
    }

    public void ShowUserControl(object context)
    {
        if (ChangeControlVisibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
            ChangeControlVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            ChangeControlVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    private ICommand _showUserControlCommand;

    public ICommand ButtonClickCommand
    {
        get { return _showUserControlCommand; }
        set { _showUserControlCommand = value; }
    }
    #endregion
```

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="RegistrationApp.Views.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                  xmlns:m="clr-namespace:RegistrationApp.Models"
                  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:RegistrationApp.ViewModels"
                  xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:RegistrationApp.Views"
                  xmlns:cl="clr-namespace:RegistrationApp.Classes"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RegistrationApp"
                  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                  xmlns:EntityModels="clr-namespace:RegistrationApp.EntityModels" 
                  mc:Ignorable="d" 
                  Title="MainWindow" 
                  Height="750" 
                  Width="600"
                  MinHeight="600"
                  MinWidth="750">
<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <m:ParentModel x:Key="parent" />
    <vm:ParentViewModel x:Key="parentViewModel" />
    <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="mainViewModel" />
    <vw:AddParentUserControl x:Key="addParentUserControl" />
</Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource mainViewModel}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20px" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20px" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20px" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="20px" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/Images/Mobiliar.png" MaxHeight="300" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" />
    </Grid>
    <Controls:MetroAnimatedTabControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Controls:TabControlHelper.IsUnderlined="True" Controls:TabControlHelper.Transition="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14">
        <TabItem Header="Parent" Controls:TabControlHelper.Transition="Normal" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="110">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,4">
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="24" Width="Auto" Margin="20,10,0,0" Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image MinHeight="10" MinWidth="10" Source="/Images/add_icon.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,0,2,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Add" FontSize="12" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="24" Width="Auto" Margin="10,10,0,0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image MinHeight="10" MinWidth="10" Source="/Images/delete_icon.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,0,2,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Delete" FontSize="12" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="24" Width="Auto" Margin="10,10,0,0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image MinHeight="10" MinWidth="10" Source="/Images/edit_icon.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,0,2,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Edit" FontSize="12" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <DataGrid x:Name="dgvParent" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" SelectionMode="Single" BorderThickness="2" Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue"  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource parentViewModel}}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserAddRows="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PId}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Id" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PLastName}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Last Name" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PFirstName}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="First Name" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PMiddleName}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Middle Name" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PAddress}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Address" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PContactNo}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Contact Number" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PEmail}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Email" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PCreatedOn}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Created On" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PUpdatedAt}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Updated At" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

My advise is not to use a DataContext that is an `ObservableCollection`.

A `WPF Window` references a `ViewModel` instance. 
In that ViewModel place a property that is an `ObservableCollection` instead

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<ParentModel> _myItems = new ObservableCollection<ParentModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<ParentModel> MyItems
    {
       get { return _myItems; }
    }

    public void AddParent(ParentModel parentModel)
    {        
        this.MyItems.Add(parentModel);
    }
}
```

Then set your Window DataContext to an instance of `MyViewModel`.
*Although not being the best practice, you may set it in the code behind of your window  in the constructor*

```
/* window constructor */
public MyWindow()
{
   this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
}
```

And finally in your XAML

```
<DataGrid ... ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
```

*and no need to set DataContext in the DataGrid*

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that there is another view model that is bound to the grid of the mainwindow, that view model is used to make the user control visible when clicking a button. I'll edit my question.